# React CASL conditions not working in production mode - Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, casl

I have a can function with condition. To enable composing messages when the condition satisfies. This is working perfectly in development mode, But when I try to run it in Production mode, The can method always gives me `false`

```
can('compose', 'Ticket', {
   phase: 'Tier 3',
});
```

```
const ticket = new Ticket({ phase: 'Tier 3' })
const canCompose = (ability.can('compose', ticket));
```

But canCompose always return `false` in production mode.
Do I have to change anything in configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in production mode all class names and function names are mangled (i.e., minified). That's why CASL can't determine subject type correctly.

This is written in [documentation about subject type detection](https://casl.js.org/v4/en/guide/subject-type-detection#how-does-casl-detect-subject-type).

So, you have 2 options:

1. Use classes instead of strings when define and check abilities per type

   ```js
   class Ticket {}
   can('compose', Ticket, { ... });

   ability.can('compose', Ticket);
   ability.can('compose', new Ticket(...))
   ```
2. Or define static `modelName` property on your classes:

   ```js
   class Ticket {
     static modelName = 'Ticket'
   }

   can('compose', 'Ticket', { ... });

   ability.can('compose', 'Ticket');
   ability.can('compose', new Ticket(...))
   ```

Comment: Thanks @Sergii Stotskyi, This solution worked for me. I have opted for 2nd option. Thanks a lot man.

Comment: This worked. If you choose option 2, you can just do `Ticket.modelName = 'Ticket'` outside the class to avoid linter warning with the suggested approach.